# React Native FlatList makes app extremely slow after 10 elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, asyncstorage

I am trying to build a simple stopwatch app in react-native. I'm using AsyncStorage to store the time recorded data into local storage, along with that I would like to display a table that shows all the recorded times. The core idea is that when a person presses and holds a LottieView animation, it will start a timer, when they press out, the timer stops, records in AsyncStorage and then updates the table.

After 10 elements, my FlatList (inside TimeTable.jsx) becomes extremely slow and I am not sure why. The component that is causing this error is I believe `TimeTable.jsx` but I am not quite sure why.

***src/components/Timer/TimeTable.jsx***

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, FlatList  } from "react-native";
import { Divider, List, ListItem } from '@ui-kitten/components'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const getRecordedEventsTable = async (dbKey) => {
  try {
    let currentDataArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem(dbKey);
    return currentDataArray ? JSON.parse(currentDataArray) : [];
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
  <ListItem
  title={`${item.timeRecorded / 1000} ${index + 1}`}
  description={`${new Date(item.timestamp)} ${index + 1}`}
   />
)

export const TimeTable = ({storageKey, timerOn}) => {
  const [timeArr, setTimeArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getRecordedEventsTable(storageKey).then((res) => {
        setTimeArr(res)
    })

  }, [timerOn])

  return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.container}
        data={timeArr}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={Divider}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.timestamp.toString()}
      />
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      maxHeight: 200,
    },
  });
```

***src/components/Timer/Timer.jsx***

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react'
import {
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Pressable,
} from 'react-native';
import {Layout, Button, Text} from '@ui-kitten/components';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {TimeTable} from './TimeTable'

const STORAGE_KEY = 'dataArray'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1, 
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#E8EDFF"
    },
    seconds: {
        fontSize: 40,
        paddingBottom: 50,
    }
})

const getRecordedEventsTable = async () => {
    try {
        let currentDataArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY)
        return currentDataArray ? JSON.parse(currentDataArray) : []
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

const addToRecordedEventsTable = async (item) => {
    try {
        let dataArray = await getRecordedEventsTable()
        dataArray.push(item)
    
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
            STORAGE_KEY,
            JSON.stringify(dataArray)
            )
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}

// ...

const Timer = () => {
    const [isTimerOn, setTimerOn] = useState(false)
    const [runningTime, setRunningTime] = useState(0)
    const animation = useRef(null);

    const handleOnPressOut = () => {
        setTimerOn(false)
        addToRecordedEventsTable({
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            timeRecorded: runningTime
        })

        setRunningTime(0)
    }

     useEffect(() => {
        let timer = null

        if(isTimerOn) {
            animation.current.play()

            const startTime = Date.now() - runningTime
            timer = setInterval(() => {
                setRunningTime(Date.now() - startTime)
            })
        } else if(!isTimerOn) {
            animation.current.reset()
            clearInterval(timer)
        }

        return () => clearInterval(timer)
    }, [isTimerOn])

    return (
        <View>
            <Pressable onPressIn={() => setTimerOn(true)} onPressOut={handleOnPressOut}>
                <LottieView ref={animation} style={{width: 300, height: 300}} source={require('../../../assets/record.json')} speed={1.5}/>
            </Pressable>
            <Text style={styles.seconds}>{runningTime/1000}</Text>
            <TimeTable storageKey={STORAGE_KEY} timerOn={isTimerOn} />
            <Button onPress={resetAsyncStorage}>Reset Async</Button>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Timer
```

Any help, appreciated. Thanks.

---

EDIT:
Received the following warning in console:

```
VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update - make sure your renderItem function renders components that follow React performance best practices like PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate, etc. Object {
  "contentLength": 1362.5,
  "dt": 25161,
  "prevDt": 368776,
```

---

EDIT:
In `Timer.jsx`, I have a Text View in the render function as follows:
`<Text style={styles.seconds}>{runningTime/1000}</Text>`, this part is supposed to show the stopwatch value and update with the timer.
As the FlatList gets bigger, this is the part that becomes extremely laggy.

My suspicion is that as this is trying to re-render constantly, the children component `TimeTable.jsx` is also re-rendering constantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.
The main culprit for the slowness was that in the parent component `Timer.jsx` because the `timerOn` props is changing everytime the user presses the button, the whole children component is trying to re-render and that AsyncStorage call is being called everytime. This is the reason that the {runningTime/1000} is rendering very slowly. Because everytime the timerOn component changes all child components have been queued to re-render.

The solution for this was to render the Table component from a parent of Timer and not inside the Timer component and maintain a state in Timer which is passed back to the parent and then passed to the Table component.

This is what my parent component looks like now:

```
  const [timerStateChanged, setTimerStateChanged] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Timer setTimerStateChanged={setTimerStateChanged} />
      <View
        style={{
          borderBottomColor: "grey",
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
        }}
      />
      <TimeTable timerOn={timerStateChanged} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

A better way would be to use something like React context or Redux.

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have a loop here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getRecordedEventsTable(storageKey).then((res) => {
        setTimeArr(res)
    })

  }, [timeArr, timerOn])
```

`useEffect` will get called every time `timeArr` is updated. Then, inside you call your async `getRecordedEventsTable`, and every time that finishes, it'll call `setTimeArr`, which will set `timeArr`, triggering the sequence to start again.

Comment: Hey @jnpdx, I took your suggestion and also fixed a minor bug in my code where I wasn't spreading the props correctly. This improves the performance and shows the list, however, the problem still persists after 30 elements. I think it is trying to re-render every element of the list too often, not sure how to solve that.

Comment: This would really surprise me if this were a big hit, but what happens if you make `description` some dummy text for right now that doesn't create a new `Date` for each row each time?

Comment: That seem to make it very slightly better, but the problem still persists. Also weirdly enough, it seems to perform better in the iOS simulator than my expo go client on the phone. @jnpdx

Comment: Here is a hypothesis: could it be that in the parent component `Timer.jsx` because the `timerOn` props is changing everytime the user presses the button, the whole children component is trying to re-render and that AsyncStorage call is being called everytime? Could this be the reason that the `<Text style={styles.second}>{runningTime/1000}</Text>` is rendering very slowly?

Comment: I say this because it seems that it's the `<Text style={styles.second}>{runningTime/1000}</Text>` component inside `Timer.jsx` which is supposed to show the value of the stopwatch's current time is the one that is lagging constantly. The LottieView animation works smoothly and the FlatList is scrollable. But the runningTime Text lags, I assume because the FlatList is trying to re-render while that UI is trying to update. 
Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: I think your suspicion is a good one. I'd suggest tearing out/mocking the functionality you expect to be the issue and seeing if that's truly the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

For optimizing the `FlatList` you can use different parameters that are available. You can read this https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration.

Also you might consider using `useCallback` hook for renderItems function.

I would recommend reading this https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-flatlist-with-hooks-in-react-native-and-some-optimization-configs-7bf4d02c59a0